# add net a new card on ubuntu

Tags: networking

I have a net card named eth0,and then I add a new net card ,sometimes it will named eth1,sometimes it will named eth0,and my old eth0 will changed to eth1,this will influence my network,because /etc/network/interfaces eth name will not compare with Mac,so the network will wrong.I just want to knew how ubuntu control this.I use a ubuntu based linux,and there is not 75-presistent rules file,and i copy this file from ubuntu,it doesn't work,i also copy write_net_rules,set grub biosdevname and net.ifname,it still doesn't work,thank you!

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version. As of 15.10 Ubuntu uses [predictable names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/).

Comment: >I use a ubuntu based linux 
Are you sure you are using ubuntu or an official ubuntu flavour?

Comment: It doesn't have to do with  predictable names. the netcard which is  reinitialized at first becomes eth0. 
Maybe it is possible to bound the name at a special card.

Comment: @user966203 No, it has everything to do with the feature commented above. And here we only support Ubuntu and official derivatives. With that behavior you either have a non official derivative  or a very old, unsupported, Ubuntu.